# Decorating dynamically formed Table View Cells: Adding UIButton to contentView or accessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I want to decorate the tableViewCells and add a button to the content view of a certain cell.
I want this piece of code below to do that. However, I cannot observe the button either at contentView or at accessoryView.

Another question in my debugging process is that when I print the x and y location of the tableViewCells with this line: `NSLog(@"Cell frame origin x: %f y: %f", cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y);` I get the output:

```
origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000 
origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000 
origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000
```

Note that `destinationName` array has three items.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // define the cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";
    // get the cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // set the content of each cell
    NSString *route = [destinationName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:route];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[originName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //define a button
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + 100 ,
                             cell.frame.origin.y + 5,
                             40, 30)];
    NSLog(@"Cell frame origin x: %f y: %f", cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y);
    //Output for this code is: origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000
    [btn setTag:indexPath.row];
    [btn setTitle:@"Btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Add this button to the contentView of the cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
    //[cell.accessoryView addSubview:btn];

    return cell;
}
```

How can I successfully put the button on the contentView of the tableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

Apple have created nice documentation for its library.

You should read it first: [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)

Then try theirs examples: [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem from this [blog post](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/).

Answer (score -1):

First thing:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

In the first run, when there are no cells to dequeue - this returns "nil".
You have to handle that and create new cell.

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Second thing is - if cell will be dequeued (if you scroll table view outside a visible range and back) - your code will always add a subview - several times to the same reused cell. Better approach will be to create custom class and add subview when you initialize it. If you want shortcut - do it in the code block above if(cell === nil) - when you create new instance.

Inside that function you just created a cell - it will be returned to tableview which asked for it - only than you could try to track x, y coordinates.

All above combines into that code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// define the cell identifier
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";
// get the cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

//define a button
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(100,5, 40, 30)]; //coordinates are x,y inside cell - top-left is 0,0
    //Output for this code is: origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000
    [btn setTag:indexPath.row];
    [btn setTitle:@"Btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Add this button to the contentView of the cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
}

// set the content of each cell
NSString *route = [destinationName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:route];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[originName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you downvote an answer, please at least leave a comment so I can improve on it